# <Switch> component matching null value in react-router-4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to migrate to use React Router 4 and having some trouble understanding the logic of the `<Switch>` component as it's used in the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match) to handle a 404 (or unmatched) route.

For my entry JavaScript file, I have the following routes set up.

**index.js**

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
    <Route path="/email-verification" component={EmailVerification} />
    <Route component={App} />
</Switch>
```

The `Login` component will check to see if the user is authenticated, and if so, redirect the user to the `/dashboard` route (via `history.replace`).

The `App` component is only accessible when the user is authenticated and it has a similar check to redirect the user to `/login` if she is not.

In my `App` component I have more specified routes that I can be sure are only accessible if the user is logged in.

**App.js**

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="/accounts" component={Account} />
    <Authorize permissions={['view-admin']}>
        <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
    </Authorize>
    <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

*Herein lies my problem*. The `Authorize` component checks against the permissions passed to see if the user has those permissions, **if so**, it renders the children directly, **if not**, it returns `null` from `render()`.

The expected behavior here is that the `<Route path="/admin" />` does not render at all when there are insufficient permissions and the `<Route component={NotFound} />` component renders.

According to the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match):

> A  renders the first child  that matches. A 
>   with no path always matches.

However, if I go to any route declared *after* the `<Authorize>` component, the router is matching to `null`. This means that, based on the example above, going to `/users` returns null. Is the expected behavior of react-router to return the first match in a `<Switch/>` component, even if it's a `null` value?

*How can I provide a "catch-all" route (404) for such a situation without creating a `<PrivateRoute>` component for each of the many, authenticated routes in App.js? Should a `null` value really produce a match?*

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution on this?

Comment: I believe that the problem was due to my <Authorize> component, I never found out why this was this case, though.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, react-router's `Switch` component won't work with routes nested inside other components like in your example.  If you check [the docs for Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch), it says:

> All children of a <Switch> should be <Route> or <Redirect> elements.

... so your `Authorize` component is not actually legal there as a direct child of `Switch`.

If you have a read through [the source code of the Switch component](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js), you'll see that it rather evilly reads the props of each of its children and manually applies react-router's `matchPath` method on each child's `path` (or `from`) prop to determine which one should be rendered.

So, what's happening in your case is `Switch` iterates through its children until it gets to your `Authorize` component.  It then looks at that component's props, finding neither a `path` or `from` prop, and calls `matchPath` on an undefined path.  As you note yourself, "a <Route> with no path always matches", so `matchPath` returns true, and Switch renders your `Authorize` component (ignoring any subsequent Routes or Redirects, since it believes it found a match).  The nested '/admin' route inside your `Authorize` component doesn't match the current path however, so you get a null result back from the render.

I'm facing a similar situation at work.  My plan to work around it is to replace react-router's `Switch` in my routing code with a custom component which iterates through its children, manually rendering each one in turn, and returning the result of the first one that returns something other than null.  I'll update this answer when I've given it a shot.

**Edit:** Well, that didn't work.  I couldn't work out a supported way to manually invoke "render" on the children.  Sorry I couldn't give you a workaround to `Switch`'s limitations.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone reads this in >= 2019, one way to deal with this behaviour is to simply wrap the Route-component like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

type Props = {
  permissions: string[]
  componentWhenNotAuthorized?: React.ElementType
}

const AuthorizedRoute: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  permissions,
  componentWhenNotAuthorized: ComponentWhenNotAuthorized,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const isAuthorized = someFancyAuthorizationLogic(permissions)

  return isAuthorized
    ? <Route {...rest} />
    : ComponentWhenNotAuthorized
      ? <ComponentWhenNotAuthorized {...rest} />
      : null
}

export default AuthorizedRoute
```

Then, simply use it as such:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import AuthorizedRoute from 'some/path/AuthorizedRoute'
import Account from 'some/path/Account'
import Admin from 'some/path/Admin'
import Dashboard from 'some/path/Dashboard'
import NotFound from 'some/path/NotFound'
import Users from 'some/path/Users'

const AppRouter: React.FunctionComponent = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route
      component={Account}
      path='/accounts'
    />
    <AuthorizedRoute
      component={Admin}
      componentWhenNotAuthorized={NotFound}
      path='/admin'
      permissions={['view-admin']}
    />
    <Route
      component={Dashboard}
      path='/dashboard'
    />
    <Route
      component={Users}
      path='/users'
    />
    <Route
      component={NotFound}
    />
  </Switch>
)

export default AppRouter
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar idea to what Robert said, here's how I did it

```
class NullComponent extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentBeRenderedByRoute() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

class CustomSwitch extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // React.Children.map returns components even for null, which 
      const children = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children).map(child => {
        const { render, shouldComponentBeRenderedByRoute } = child.type.prototype;
        if (shouldComponentBeRenderedByRoute && !shouldComponentBeRenderedByRoute.call(child)) {
         return null;
        }

        if (shouldComponentBeRenderedByRoute) {
          return render.call(child);
        }

        return child;
      });

      return <Switch>{children}</Switch>;
    );
  }
}
```

then use it just do

```
<CustomSwitch>
  <Route path... />
  <NullComponent />
  <Route path... />
</CustomSwitch>
```

here, a component without `shouldComponentBeRenderedByRoute` function is assumed to be a valid Route component from `react-router`, but you can add more condition (maybe use path props) to check if it's a valid Route