# Nested <Switch/> Tag in React Router-v4 returns null

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

So, I've been struggling to get nested  Routes to work in my application.
For some reason, even though all the routes are defined, the  returns null.

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import tabData from '../../data/tabData';
    import Tab from './Tab';
    import Homepage from '../Homepage/Homepage';
    import contactContainer from '../contactContainer/contactContainer';
    import leadContainer from '../leadContainer/leadContainer';
    import { Switch, Route, Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    import './Dashboard.css';

    class Dashboard extends Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          tabs: tabData,
          page:''
        }
      }
      render(){
        return(
          <div className="row navigation">
            <div className="col-md-3 left-nav">
              <div className="user-details">
                <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/149/149071.png"/>
                <h3>John Doe</h3>
              </div>
              <Tab tabs={this.state.tabs}/>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-9">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/lead" component={leadContainer}/>
                <Route path="/home" component={Homepage}/>
                <Route path="/contacts" component={contactContainer}/>
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default Dashboard;
```

And here's what the React Dev Tools is notifying me:

Picture of  Tag having 'null' Routes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmWWv.jpg

Would deeply appreciate it if someone could help with this - I've been struggling with it for days!

I found this article that seems to address the same issue, but with no solution yet: [<Switch> component matching null value in react-router-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416450/switch-component-matching-null-value-in-react-router-4)

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested `Route`s don't work by stacking on one another. For example, I see in your screenshot you have a `Dashboard` component which matches `/dashboard`.

You would *think* that you could, then, just put `Route`s that match `/lead` or `/home` inside the `Dashboard` component...but you can't.

**Each `Route` component, regardless of it's position in the tree, needs an absolute path.** Judging by the fact that the `Dashboard` component is being rendered, you are already on `/dashboard`, which means you inherently can't be on `/lead` or `/home`, etc etc.

This means that your `Route`s in your component should be, `/dashboard/lead`, `/dashboard/home`, and `/dashboard/contacts`. Or, you could use the `this.props.match` prop, and do something like:

```
<Route path={this.props.match.path + "/home"} component={Homepage}/>
```

I know, sometimes I wish that nested `Route`s would automatically stack too! But I can imagine the absolute headache that would cause for the developers of the library, and most likely even many developers using the library.

Comment: You're a life-saver! Thank you so much for this, it works beautifully! I've been messing around with the routes for days :D